# Is TabDefault the only option for placing a group on ribbon?

Tags: outlook, office-js, add-in, outlook-web-addins

After years of developing COM add-ins, I am now doing a outlook js add-in. So I am newbie to this enviroment.

I have a couple of questions regarding the ribbon architecture.

From what I have read, I  believe the TabDefault is the only option for the ribbon group. I am trying to place my ribbon group at a specific location and emulate the COM add-in. For example, for my Outlook COM add-in I can place my options button that pops up a dialog on the TabMail ribbon before group GroupQuickSteps. Is the Outlook ribbon only limited to TabDefault?

I would like to design my ribbon to have one button on the compose ribbon and one button on the read (pop-out) button. Then I would have two buttons on the main ribbon (TabMail). All buttons would perform different functions. Can I define separate logic for each ribbon/window? The only example I see is that Contoso sample app. Kind of confused about the manifest and limitations. Looks like that example pops up on all windows.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web add-ins don't support ribbon customizations you could do with a COM add-in. But web add-ins provide the ability to create ribbon commands. You can read more about them in the [Add-in commands for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook) article.

### Add-in commands are supported for four scenarios:

- Reading a message

  When the user is reading a message in the reading pane or in the Message tab for a pop-out read form, add-in commands added to the default tab appear on the Home tab.
- Composing a message

  When the user is composing a message, add-in commands added to the default tab appear on the Message tab.
- Creating or viewing an appointment or meeting as the organizer

  When creating or viewing an appointment or meeting as the organizer, add-in commands added to the default tab appear on the Meeting, Meeting Occurrence, Meeting Series, or Appointment tabs on pop-out forms. However, if the user selects an item in the calendar but doesn't open the pop-out, the add-in's ribbon group won't be visible in the ribbon.
- Viewing a meeting as an attendee

  When viewing a meeting as an attendee, add-in commands added to the default tab appear on the Meeting, Meeting Occurrence, or Meeting Series tabs on pop-out forms. However, if a user selects an item in the calendar but doesn't open the pop-out, the add-in's ribbon group won't be visible in the ribbon
- Using a module extension

  When using a module extension, add-in commands appear on the extension's custom tab.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Much appreciated